# Image is shown in pop up box correctly, but when saving returns an undefined error. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Using parse.com and JS SDK, at the moment `badgeselected` is being saved as undefined. However the image is being captured within the pop up box correctly.

I must have missed something basic, like having to declare the the badgeselected variable again?

---

Pop up box that contains the image to be saved.

```
               $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.go img').css('cursor', 'pointer');
                    $('.go').on('click', 'img', function (e) {
                        $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');
                        $('#modal').reveal({
                            animation: 'fade',
                            animationspeed: 600,
                            closeonbackgroundclick: true,
                            dismissmodalclass: 'close'
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
```

---

Where the image is saved to parse

```
   var MyBadge = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");

                var badgeselected = $('#badgeselect .go').attr("src");

                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#send").click(function () {

                        var myBadge = new MyBadge();
                        var badgeselected = $('#badgeselect .go').attr("src");

                        var uploadercomment = $('#UploaderComment').val();
                        myBadge.set("BadgeName", badgeselected); //got this working using .set 
                        myBadge.set("Comment", uploadercomment); //got this working using .set 
                        myBadge.set("uploadedBy", Parse.User.current());

                        myBadge.save(null, {
                            success: function (results) {

                                console.log("Done");
                                //location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function (contact, error) {
                                // The save failed.

                                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                            }
                        });

                        return false;
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved by changing the line

```
 var badgeselected = $('#badgeselect').attr("src");
```

to

```
 var badgeselected = $('#badgeselect img').attr("src");
```

Easy when you know how :-/